# Error mvn install java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/Scanner

Tags: java, maven, noclassdeffounderror, plexus

Im trying compile the project but this error showing:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/util/Scanner

Using Java 11 and Maven v3.8.1 by Intellij

I set:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                <artifactId>plexus-utils</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.15</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

But not working.

I tried with version maven compiler more recent too

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>11</source>
                <target>11</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Why have you added the plexus-utils as a dependency for the plugin? Also I would suggest to use most recent version of maven-compiler-plugin (3.11.0) See https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ ... and remove the supplemental dependency ...Furthermore I would suggest to use most recent version of Maven (https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi)

Comment: This looks like you might have stumbled upon a workaround to an older problem.  Are you sure you even need this dependency?

Comment: I tried with this version of maven compiler and deleted plugin, but still show this error